# ddply using "group_by" logic

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to use [ddply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/ddply) to find the smallest distance between two positions `pos` **where the corresponding chrom is the same** in two dataframes:

```
head(bps, 10)
   chrom pos iteration
1      1   4         1
2      1  14         1
3      1  68         1
4      1  79         1
5      1 200         1
6      1 205         1
7      1 270         1
8      1 304         1
9      2   7         1
10     2  13         1

head(flocs)
  chrom pos
1     1 100
2     1 200
3     1 220
4     1 312
5     2 500
6     2 501
```

As an example, for the first line in `bps`, I want to find the closest `pos` in `flocs` where `chrom` = `1`, which gives a value of -96.

The pseudocode for what I'm trying to do is:

```
foreach iteration (bps$iteration):
  foreach chrom (bps$chrom):
    foreach pos (bps$pos):
      features_pos = pos in dataframe flocs closest to pos on the same chromosome
      min_dist     = feature_pos - pos

      return features_pos, min_dist
```

I am trying to do this with [ddply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/ddply):

```
minDists <- ddply(bp_data, c("chrom", "pos"), function(x) {
    index <-  which.min(abs(flocs$pos[which(flocs$chrom==x$chrom)] - x$pos))
    closestMotif <- flocs$pos[index]
    chrom <- as.character(flocs$chrom[index])
    dist <- (x$pos - closestMotif)
    data.frame(features_pos = closestMotif, pos = x$pos, min_dist = dist, feature = feature)
  })
```

But this doesn't constrain comparisons to the same chromosome:

```
head(minDists, 10)

   chrom features_pos pos min_dist  feature
1      1          100   4      -96 feature1
2      1          100  14      -86 feature1
3      1          100  68      -32 feature1
4      1          100  79      -21 feature1
5      1          200 200        0 feature1
6      1          200 205        5 feature1
7      1          312 270      -42 feature1
8      1          312 304       -8 feature1
9      2          100   7      -93 feature1 # bps chrom=2, flocs chrom=1
10     2          100  13      -87 feature1 # bps chrom=2, flocs chrom=1
```

The expected output here is:

```
   chrom features_pos pos min_dist  feature
1      1          100   4      -96 feature1
2      1          100  14      -86 feature1
3      1          100  68      -32 feature1
4      1          100  79      -21 feature1
5      1          200 200        0 feature1
6      1          200 205        5 feature1
7      1          312 270      -42 feature1
8      1          312 304       -8 feature1
9      2          500   7      -493 feature1 # bp1 chrom=2, flocs chrom=2
10     2          500  13      -487 feature1 # bp1 chrom=2, flocs chrom=2
```

I thought that by providing the columns `c("chrom", "pos")` essentially performed a `group_by` to the function call.

**Is there any way that I can improve what I've written to achieve the desired result?**

---

```
bps <- structure(list(chrom = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"
), class = "factor"), pos = c(4L, 14L, 68L, 79L, 200L, 205L, 
270L, 304L, 7L, 13L, 23L, 39L, 100L, 150L, 17L, 55L, 75L, 79L, 
102L, 109L, 123L, 155L, 157L, 200L, 260L, 299L, 300L, 320L, 323L, 
345L, 450L, 550L), iteration = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

```
flocs <- structure(list(chrom = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), pos = c(100L, 
200L, 220L, 312L, 500L, 501L, 123L, 444L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` approach using a rolling join...

**updated answer**

*(initially forgot all about the by-reference joining, which is faster and most certainly shorter ;-) )*

```
library( data.table )
#set data as data.table
setDT( bps, key = c("chrom", "pos") )
setDT( flocs, key = c("chrom", "pos") )
#perform by-reference rolling join
bps[, mindist := pos - flocs[bps, x.pos, roll = "nearest"]][]
```

**output**

```
#     chrom pos iteration mindist
#  1:     1   4         1     -96
#  2:     1  14         1     -86
#  3:     1  68         1     -32
#  4:     1  79         1     -21
#  5:     1 200         1       0
#  6:     1 205         1       5
#  7:     1 270         1     -42
#  8:     1 304         1      -8
#  9:     2   7         1    -493
# 10:     2  13         1    -487
# 11:     2  23         1    -477
# 12:     2  39         1    -461
# 13:     2 100         1    -400
# 14:     2 150         1    -350
# 15:     3  17         1    -106
# 16:     3  55         1     -68
# 17:     3  75         1     -48
# 18:     3  79         1     -44
# 19:     3 102         1     -21
# 20:     3 109         1     -14
# 21:     3 123         1       0
# 22:     3 155         1      32
# 23:     3 157         1      34
# 24:     3 200         1      77
# 25:     3 260         1     137
# 26:     3 299         1    -145
# 27:     3 300         1    -144
# 28:     3 320         1    -124
# 29:     3 323         1    -121
# 30:     3 345         1     -99
# 31:     3 450         1       6
# 32:     3 550         1     106
#     chrom pos iteration mindist
```

## Benchmarking answer until now

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#        Ronak_base  2.355879  2.555768  2.973069  2.626415  2.773581  8.016016   100
# Wimpel_data.table  1.697921  2.035788  2.416199  2.209616  2.361001 17.724528   100
#   Pawel_tidyverse 14.845354 15.310505 16.333158 15.814819 16.541618 24.077871   100


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Ronak_base = {
    bps$min_dist <- unlist(mapply(return_min_value, unique(bps$chrom), split(bps$pos, bps$chrom)))
  },
  Wimpel_data.table = {
    setDT( bps, key = c("chrom", "pos") )
    setDT( flocs, key = c("chrom", "pos") )
    #perform by-reference rolling join
    bps[, mindist := pos - flocs[bps, x.pos, roll = "nearest"]][]
  },
  Pawel_tidyverse = {
    bps %>%
      select(-iteration) %>%
      unite('bps') %>%
      crossing(flocs %>% unite('flocks')) %>%
      separate(bps, c('chrom_bps', 'pos')) %>%
      separate(flocks, c('chrom_flocks', 'features_pos')) %>%
      filter(chrom_bps == chrom_flocks) %>%
      select(-chrom_flocks) %>%
      rename_at(1, ~'chrom') %>%
      mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
      mutate(min_dist = pos - features_pos) %>%
      group_by(chrom, pos) %>%
      filter(abs(min_dist) == min(abs(min_dist)))
  }
)
```

Looks like my data-table answer and the answer by Ronak Shah are pretty close together. I believe that data.table will gain the clear advantage when the data-sets are getting lager-huge (but I haven't tested)..

Answer (score 2):

My base R attempt by creating a helper function (`return_min_value`). This function subset `flocs` based on current `chrom` and then returns the minimum value after subtracting it from `pos`. We `split` the `pos` column based on `chrom` and pass these values along with `unique` `chrom` values in `mapply` to `return_min_value` function.

```
return_min_value <- function(x, y) {
   sapply(y, function(p) {
     vals = p - flocs$pos[flocs$chrom == x]
     vals[which.min(abs(vals))]
  })
}

bps$min_dist <- unlist(mapply(return_min_value,
                       unique(bps$chrom), split(bps$pos, bps$chrom)))


bps
#   chrom pos iteration min_dist
#1      1   4         1      -96
#2      1  14         1      -86
#3      1  68         1      -32
#4      1  79         1      -21
#5      1 200         1        0
#6      1 205         1        5
#7      1 270         1      -42
#8      1 304         1       -8
#9      2   7         1     -493
#10     2  13         1     -487
#...
```

Comment: Although quite slow for large datasets (30k +)

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

bps %>%
  select(-iteration) %>%
  unite('bps') %>%
  crossing(flocs %>% unite('flocks')) %>%
  separate(bps, c('chrom_bps', 'pos')) %>%
  separate(flocks, c('chrom_flocks', 'features_pos')) %>%
  filter(chrom_bps == chrom_flocks) %>%
  select(-chrom_flocks) %>%
  rename_at(1, ~'chrom') %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  mutate(min_dist = pos - features_pos) %>%
  group_by(chrom, pos) %>%
  filter(abs(min_dist) == min(abs(min_dist)))
```

Output:

```
  chrom   pos features_pos min_dist
   <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1     4          100      -96
 2     1    14          100      -86
 3     1    68          100      -32
 4     1    79          100      -21
 5     1   200          200        0
 6     1   205          200        5
 7     1   270          312      -42
 8     1   304          312       -8
 9     2     7          500     -493
10     2    13          500     -487
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: Where does the comparison to `flocs` happen?

Comment: @fugu Sorry. I didn't understand your question at first. See edited answer.